# I want to re-use a web app in another Django project, and want to keep forms.py in the web app

Tags: django-forms, placeholder

I wrote an app in a Django project, and would like to re-use it in another Django project. But it has project specific data in forms.py. I've been advised to move the forms.py out of the web app, but I was wondering if there's an alternative that lets me keep forms.py in the re-usable web app. (As you can see, the project specific code is a placeholder that gives the usesr search suggestions.)

```
        widgets = {  
                    'user_search_terms': 
                    forms.Textarea
                    (attrs={'rows':2, 'cols':60,'placeholder': 'examples: sleep disorder, PASC, clinical trials, sleep onset, spoon theory '}),
                     
                  }
```

[image: This is the resulting placeholder that the user sees])

I haven't tried any change yet, as this is the first time I'll be using one of my existing apps in a new Django project, so I'm at the starting gate with figuring out whether I can keep my forms.py in the web app. It seems like this should be a common question, as placeholders in forms are common, but I couldn't find the specific answer to this.